# JPA @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED): different discriminator value for same class

Tags: inheritance, jpa

Is it possibile to map two differents discriminator values to the same concrete java class?

Something like this:

```
@DiscriminatorValue("4")
@DiscriminatorValue("5")
public class CartaImpl extends RapportoImpl implements Carta, Cloneable {
```

Another question: is it possible to have a default implementation when no class is provided for an indicator field value for not raising this exception?

```
Missing class for indicator field value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Makes no sense. If instances of that class have two possible values of the discriminator in the DB then create two different classes in the same inheritance tree, one per value of the discriminator

Comment: Ok just done. Now the super class holds the implementation while the subclass only defines his own discriminator value.

Answer (score 0):

Why using two different values to mean the same thing? And why use values that don't mean anything? I would fix the data, rather than trying to map invalid data :

```
update rapporto set discriminator = '4' where discriminator = '5';
update rapporto set discriminator = '0' where discriminator not in ('0,', '1', '2', '3', '4');
```

(assuming 0 is the discriminator of the default entity, and 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 are the valid discriminator values).

Comment: Because I use a lagacy database. I cannot fix the data, but only work as slave process. The only way I think is to have a @MappedSuperclass that hold the implementation and the relative sublclasses.

Answer (score 0):

This is not defined in JPA, but some providers do support more complex indicators.

If using EclipseLink, you can use a ClassExtractor to define your own code to determine the Class to use for each row.

See, http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Inheritance#No_class_discriminator_column